# String concatenation with "[" "]" results in 0 in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the following code echo $d prints value 0

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Enter the IP address: "
read server
a=":"
b="["
c="]"
d=$b$server$c
echo $d
```

Comment: `$ ./test.sh 
Enter the IP address: 192.168.0.1
[192.168.0.1[`. Seems to work for me. What shell are you using? (Also not that you do not use `$c`)

Comment: This script works correctly, how are you running it?

Comment: Sorry it was typing mistake,code runs when I try to concatenate with $b but I want d as [IP_address]

Comment: _Which shell are you using?_ This works fine in bash.

Comment: I'm using bash shell on RHEL6.0

Comment: Still works for me, using bash, I get output like this: `[192.168.1.1]`.

Comment: It may help, I'm  using the following shell
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: I grew up with a real Bourne shell; I'd use `d="$b$server$c"` automatically to avoid risks (and `echo "$d"` too).  I doubt if you'd have any problems with the double quotes.  But I'm not sure why you're running into trouble, either.

Comment: yup,This works if I put the string and remove echo...
Thanks

Comment: What you say doesn't make any sense. The script works. What do you mean "put the string"? Please edit the title to better describe your problem.

Comment: I edited the script as per Jonathan said and removed the echo line
now the script works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using `printf`. Use `printf` instead of `echo`. This works just fine:

```
printf "Enter the IP address: "
read server
a=":"
b="["
c="]"
d="${b}${server}${c}"
printf "%s\n"  $d
```

Whenever you are having problems with `echo`, you can use `printf` just like the way I show it. In fact, I recommend that you use it instead of echo. Here's an example:

```
echo -n "Enter a string: "
read string
echo "$string"
```

Seems simple enough, but what if I entered `-foo` as my string? The echo will fail. However, this will work:

```
printf "%s" "Enter a string: "
read string
printf "%s\n" $string
```

No matter what you enter in for `$string`.

I did change the setting of `$d` by using quotes and curly braces. If you don't use quotes when setting `d`, and someone enters in `this * is a string` for your IP address, your program will expand `*` to match all of th files in the directory. Probably something you don't want. The curly braces just make it easier to see variables when they're all smushed together like that. Plus, it'll probably put each word on its own line.

Enter `this * is a test` as your IP address and try setting `$d` without quotes and then with quotes and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you `echo` a variable without quoting it, the contents are subject to, among other things, glob expansion. A glob consisting of open and close square brackets with something between them is seen by the shell as a pattern which is a choice of any of the characters within.

Here's a demonstration:

```
$ mkdir newdir
$ cd newdir
$ var='[192.168.0.1]'
$ echo $var     # unquoted
[192.168.0.1]
$ touch 0
$ echo $var     # unquoted
0
$ echo "$var"   # quoted
[192.168.0.1]
```

As you can see, there is a file in the directory (after the `touch` command) called "0". There is a "0" inside the square brackets which matches. The sequence of characters inside the square brackets is simply that, not a string (when the variable is unquoted), but the duplicates are ignored. In this example, `[192.680]` is equivalent.

The lesson? You have a file named "0" in your directory. The solution? ***Always*** quote variables when their consumed.